# How do I generate numeric titled wordpress posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, command-line-interface

I would like to automatically generate some sequential Wordpress posts that have numeric titles, for example "1", "2", "3"... etc.

I'm looking for an automatic system since I would like my posts to go from "1" to "999999".

No post content or meta is required, only the titles.

I'm aware of [wp post generate](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/generate/) but I have no idea on how to use it so that the post titles have the requirements explained above.

I'm working on a demo project so search engine optimization is not a concern at the moment.

CLI usage is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that quite simply by using a `for` loop with any arbitrary range (1-99 for example - or any other range you prefer)

```
for i in {1..99}; do wp post create --post_title="This is post number $i" --post_status=publish; done
```

This will call the `wp post create` command on each iteration of the loop and append the number to the post title.

Comment: I'll be trying this ASAP. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php

// Create post object usinf for loop 
for($i=1;$i<=9999;$i++){
$my_post = array();
$my_post['post_title']    = '<?php echo $i;?>';
$my_post['post_content']  = 'This is my post-<?php echo $i;?>';
$my_post['post_status']   = 'publish';
$my_post['post_author']   = 1;
$my_post['post_category'] = array(0);
// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );"
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

wordpress appends a numeric value automatically if there's an existing post with the same post-title.

so if the permalinks are set to be `postname` the URL will look as follow:

```
my-post
my-post-1
my-post-2
etc
```

Comment: What is `automatic` about this?

Comment: just read [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_unique_post_slug/). if u ever worked with WP then u would know.

Comment: just read the question, if you did then you would know that the OP is trying to create these posts automatically, he's not interested in the very obvious fact that wordpress creates unique URL slugs....